# Probability & Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

You and a friend play a game in which the winner is the first player who has 
7 or more points and is 2 points ahead of the other player. Note that game 
involves rounds of play, and the winner gains one point in each round. 
Assume that both of you have the same ability, that is, each of you is 
equally likely to make next point in each round of play.

Suppose the current score for the game is 6-5 in your favor, what is the 
likelihood that you will eventually win the game?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps to provide what you've tried and your approach to the problem so users can provide better guidance. Regards

Comment: Let next round be round k. P(me winning game) = P(winning round k)+P(loosing round k)*p(winning k+1 and k+2)+P(loosing both k adn k+1)*P(winning k+2,k+3,k+4)+..... It keeps on gng. I am not sure if my approach is correct. Can you provide guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_k$ be the number of wins you have up until time $k$, $Y_k$ the number of wins your opponent has. $X_k \sim $ Bin($k,\frac{1}{2}$). You are interested in $X_k - Y_k$, which must exceed $2$ in order that you win. Note that $X_k - Y_k = X_k - (k - X_k) = 2X_k - k$.

Let $\tau$ be the time until the difference equals $2$. This is a hitting time. I.e. 
$$
  \tau
:= \inf\{k; 2X_k - k =2 \}.
$$
The quantity you seek is $P[\tau < \infty]$. Now 
$$
  P[\tau \geq r]
= P[X_r - Y_r < 2]
= P[X_r < 1 + r/2]
= \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor r/2 \rfloor} \binom{r}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^r
$$
and so
$$
  P[\tau < \infty]
= \lim_{r \to \infty} P[\tau < r]
= \lim_{r \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^r 
  \sum_{n=\lfloor 1+r/2 \rfloor}^r \binom{r}{n}.
$$
If we take $r \to \infty$ to be even, then the sum 
$\sum_{n= 1+r/2 }^r \binom{r}{n}$ should be equal to $\sum_{n=0}^{ r/2 } \binom{r}{n}$ by the symmetry of Pascal's triangle. The total sum of these is $2^r$, therefore the final value is 
$$
  P[\tau < \infty]
= \lim_{r \to \infty, r\in 2\mathbb{Z}} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^r 
  \sum_{n= 1+r/2 }^r \binom{r}{n}
= \lim_{r \to \infty, r\in 2\mathbb{Z}} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^r 
  2^{r-1}
= \frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: So likelihood that you will eventually win the game is 1/2 ?

Comment: Seems that way to me!

Comment: But  P(me winning game) = P(winning round k)+P(loosing round k)*p(winning k+1 and k+2)+P(loosing both k adn k+1)*P(winning k+2,k+3,k+4)+..... It keeps on gng so P(winning round k) = 1/2 so wouldnt be total prob > 0.5

Comment: Yes. My solution starts with the assumption that you both have an equal number of wins, but with your question you start off with an advantage, so you need to make a slight modification to my answer. To be precise, $P[$ win round $12]$ + $P[$ win given lose round $12]P[$ lose round $12] = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Don't mention it!